# Android : How to call method of fragment included in xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have two fragments, Fragment A & B. 
Fragment B is included in Fragment A's xml.

for eg : fragment_a.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:clickable="true"
>

<fragment android:name="com.test.FragmentB"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I want to access method in Fragment B from Fragment A.

Eg : 
 Fragment B :

```
public void releaseCamera(){
//todo: camera release here 
}
```

Fragment A :

```
 public void onButtonClick(){
  //todo : call releaseCamera() here 
//tried but didnot work
  FragmentB fragmentB =
            (FragmentB)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);
    fragmentB.releaseScannerCamera();
}
```

How can I achieve that? Should I use interface? 
Thanks,

Comment: From where did you adding thse A and B fragment .. ?

Comment: from base activity. But that doesn't matter here. You can also give solution for an activity and fragment. Where Fragment is included inside activity's xml. Now how can I access method of fragment from that activity?

Comment: First of all you remove `fragment` tag and keep `FrameLayuout` instead.
Then communication between activity and fragment or fragment and fragment you can achieve by interface .

Comment: Basically you are creating two fragment object from your base activity right. So you can call from Fragment A to interface method which present in Activity to get the object of FragmentB .

Answer (score 0):

FragmentB   fragmentB =
      (FragmentB)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);
    fragmentB.releaseScannerCamera(this);

Answer (score 0):

1. Always good approach is use FrameLayout instead Fragment.
   Add those(A and B) Fragment from activity using add method fragment manager.
2. Create interface methods in activity which will return objects of Fragment A and B. So you can get the object of fragment whenever you want, and call those method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Found simple answer. Just had to use getChildFragmentManager(). No need to create any interface on activity as both fragments are directly connected from xml.

```
FragmentB fragmentB =
        (FragmentB)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);
fragmentB.releaseScannerCamera();
```